# GCP HTTP Load balancer to TCP Load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn, google-cloud-http-load-balancer, google-cloud-network-load-balancer, kong

I am trying to figure out is how can I connect a TCP Load balancer with a HTTP/HTTPS load balancer in GCP.

I have installed kong on a GKE cluster and it creates a TCP Load balancer.

Now if I have multiple GKE clusters with Kong they all will have their own TCP Load balancers.

From a user perspective I need to then do a DNS load balancing which I don't think is always fruitful.

So I'm trying to figure out if I can use Cloud CDN, NEG and or HTTP/HTTPS load balancer to act as a front end for Kong's TCP Load balancer..

Is it possible? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: There are four types of TCP-like load balancers on GCP. Does Kong create a regional external NLB, a regional internal NLB, a global TCP proxy, or a regional TCP proxy? Most importantly, do you see any Zonal NEGs on Kubernetes already created by Kong? Please edit your quetion to add that information.